# get lat/lang/radius of center of circle that user after drawn a circle

Tags: javascript, dictionary

```
    var getCenterAndRadius = new Array();

    google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'circlecomplete', function( circle ) {

        var centercircle = circle.getCenter().toString();

        var splitleft = centercircle.split("(");
        var split123 = splitleft[1];
        var splitright = split123.split(")");
        var splitcenter = splitright[0];

        splitcenter = splitcenter.split(",");
        valLat = splitcenter[0];
        valLong = splitcenter[1];

            if (!(google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation(circle.getCenter(), UAEMap))) {    
                alert("50% of Selected area out of allowed boundaries... Please select again.");
                deleteSelectedShape();
                //return false;
        } 

        if (valLat.substr(0,1) == "-") {
            ddLatVal = valLat.substr(1,valLat.length-1);
            var sign = 1;
        } else {
            ddLatVal = valLat;
        }

        if (valLong.substr(0,1) == "-") {
            ddLongVal = valLong.substr(1,valLong.length-1);
            var sign = 1;
        } else {
            ddLongVal = valLong;
        }
        ddLatVals = ddLatVal.split(".");

        ddLongVals = ddLongVal.split(".");

        ddLatRemainder  = ("0." + ddLatVals[1]) * 60;
        dmsLatMinVals   = ddLatRemainder.toString().split(".");

        ddLongRemainder  = ("0." + ddLongVals[1]) * 60;
        dmsLongMinVals   = ddLongRemainder.toString().split(".");

        ddLatMinRemainder = ("0." + dmsLatMinVals[1]) * 60;

        ddLongMinRemainder = ("0." + dmsLongMinVals[1]) * 60;

        if(sign==1)
            var dmsResult = ddLatVals[0]+' '+dmsLatMinVals[0]+' '+Math.round(ddLatMinRemainder)+'S'+','+ddLongVals[0]+' '+dmsLongMinVals[0]+' '+Math.round(ddLongMinRemainder)+'W';
        else
            var dmsResult = ddLatVals[0]+' '+dmsLatMinVals[0]+' '+Math.round(ddLatMinRemainder)+'N'+','+ddLongVals[0]+' '+dmsLongMinVals[0]+' '+Math.round(ddLongMinRemainder)+'E';


'+Math.round(ddLatMinRemainder)+','+ddLongVals[0]+' '+dmsLongMinVals[0]+' '+Math.round(ddLongMinRemainder) + ']';

        var radius = circle.getRadius();
        getCenterAndRadius.push('0'+'|'+'0'+'|'+dmsResult+'|'+ Math.round(radius));
        document.getElementById("txtCircleLocation").value=getCenterAndRadius;

        locval = document.getElementById("txtLocation").value;
        if(locval==''){
            document.getElementById("txtLocation").value=getCenterAndRadius;
        }else{
            document.getElementById("txtLocation").value=document.getElementById("txtLocation").value+';'+getCenterAndRadius;
        }

    });
```

**how to get latitude and longitude after drawn a circle**

Comment: can you add a little context on what you try to do?

Comment: what i am trying to do is, after drawn a circle or polygon we need to get those lat/lng as per their shapes